# как можно оптимизировать код, код внутри

Tags: php, циклы

```
$W1 = "a";
For($Q = 1; $Q <= 12; $Q++){
        $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q;
        For($W = $Q; $W <= 12; $W++){
            If($W > $Q) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W;
            If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
            For($E = $W; $E <= 12; $E++){
                If($W > $Q && $E > $W) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E;
                If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                For($R = $E; $R <= 12; $R++){
                    If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R;
                    If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                    For($T = $R; $T <= 12; $T++){
                        If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E && $T > $R) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T;
                        If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                        For($Y = $T; $Y <= 12; $Y++){
                            If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E && $T > $R && $Y > $T) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y;
                            If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                            For($U = $Y; $U <= 12; $U++){
                                If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E && $T > $R && $Y > $T && $U > $Y) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y . "_" . $U;
                                If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                                For($I = $U; $I <= 12; $I++){
                                    If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E && $T > $R && $Y > $T && $U > $Y && $I > $U) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y . "_" . $U . "_" . $I;
                                    If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                                    For($O = $I; $O <= 12; $O++){
                                        If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E && $T > $R && $Y > $T && $U > $Y && $I > $U && $O > $I) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y . "_" . $U . "_" . $I. "_" . $O;
                                        If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                                        For($P = $O; $P <= 12; $P++){
                                            If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E && $T > $R && $Y > $T && $U > $Y && $I > $U && $O > $I && $P > $O) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y . "_" . $U . "_" . $I . "_" . $O . "_" . $P;
                                            If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                                            For($A = $P; $A <= 12; $A++){
                                                If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E && $T > $R && $Y > $T && $U > $Y && $I > $U && $O > $I && $P > $O && $A > $P) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y . "_" . $U . "_" . $I . "_" . $O . "_" . $P . "_" . $A;
                                                If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                                                For($S = $A; $S <= 12; $S++){
                                                    If($W > $Q && $E > $W && $R > $E && $T > $R && $Y > $T && $U > $Y && $I > $U && $O > $I && $P > $O && $A > $P && $S > $A) $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y . "_" . $U . "_" . $I . "_" . $O . "_" . $P . "_" . $A . "_" . $S;
                                                    If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Этот код генерит строки вида … "a_1_4_7"… "a_5_6_10_12"… и так далее, т.е в строке от 1 до 12 цифр, цифра слева всегда должна быть меньше цифры справа. Этот код выполняется 271 секунду :-) есть идеи как его оптимизировать? Умникам, которые закрывают посты просьба питлять мимо… С рекурсией не дружу пока,если это возможно сделать рекурсией поделитесь пожалуйста кодом, цель не сократить код, а уменьшить время выполнения

Comment: `С рекурсией не дружу пока`, мне кажется самое время познакомиться, не будете же вы каждый раз когда понадобится рекурсия вопрос на ruSO задавать?)  (извините, если что-то не так написал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаг 1.

Все эти конструкции:

```
If(..) $TVal = $W1 . "_" ...;
If(!In_Array($TVal, $PreSetArray)) $PreSetArray[] = $TVal;
```

Замените на:

```
If(..) { $TVal = $W1 . "_" ...; $PreSetArray[$TVal] = $TVal; }
```

А в самом конце кода добавьте (чтоб получить тот же массив что вы получаете сейчас):

```
$PreSetArray = array_values($PreSetArray);
```

Время сократится на порядок. Или даже больше.

Шаг 2.

Все циклы явно начинайте с подходящего значения. Т.е. всё это:

```
For($W = $Q; $W <= 12; $W++){
```

Замените на это (для всех циклов for в вашем коде добавить `+ 1`):

```
For($W = $Q + 1; $W <= 12; $W++){
```

И после этого уберите условия внутри цикла:

```
If($W > $Q) .. // такое условие можно убрать везде
```

Время сократится ещё примерно на 2 порядка.

Шаг 3.

Очевидно, что действия внутри каждого цикла - шаблонные. И их можно попробовать вынести в функцию. Для начала напишем не рекурсивную, для самого глубоко-вложенного цикла (тот, что не вызывает других внутри себя):

```
function append(&$target, $from, $prefix)
{
    for ($i = $from; $i < 13; $i++) {
        $val = "{$prefix}_{$i}";
        $target[$val] = $val;
    }
}
```

.. и заменим этот старый цикл ..

```
For($S = $A + 1; $S <= 12; $S++){
    $TVal = $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y . "_" . $U . "_" . $I . "_" . $O . "_" . $P . "_" . $A . "_" . $S;
    $PreSetArray[$TVal] = $TVal;
}
```

На вызов функции:

```
append($PreSetArray, $A + 1, $W1 . "_" . $Q . "_" . $W . "_" . $E . "_" . $R . "_" . $T . "_" . $Y . "_" . $U . "_" . $I . "_" . $O . "_" . $P . "_" . $A);
```

Шаг 4.

Теперь циклов стало на 1 меньше. Посмотрим на самый глубоко-вложенный. Заметим, что он вызывал вложенного в себя увеличивая стартовое значение цикла и меняя префикс. Давайте сделаем это прямо внутри функции превратив её в рекурсивную:

```
function append(&$target, $from, $prefix)
{
    for ($i = $from; $i < 13; $i++) {
        $val = "{$prefix}_{$i}";
        $target[$val] = $val;
        append($target, $i + 1, $val);
    }
}
```

И сразу же удаляем все циклы заменяя их одним единственным вызовом функции. Итоговый код всего скрипта:

```
function append(&$target, $from, $prefix)
{
    for ($i = $from; $i < 13; $i++) {
        $val = "{$prefix}_{$i}";
        $target[$val] = $val;
        append($target, $i + 1, $val);
    }
}
$PreSetArray = [];
append($PreSetArray, 1, "a");
$PreSetArray = array_values($PreSetArray);
```

У меня скрипт отрабатывает за `0.0016 sec`. Для сравнения ваш исходный отрабатывал за 10-12 секунд.

Comment: если убрать объявление ключа _$val_ в массиве `$target[$val] = $val;` --> `$target[] = $val;` то не понадобится _$PreSetArray = array_values($PreSetArray);_

Comment: @Эдуард всё верно, но только для последнего шага, когда мы уже гарантировали получение строго уникальных значений.

Comment: Lexx918 значения итак уникальны )

Comment: Да! это то что надо!!! время выполнения 0.0079998970031738. Большое спасибо! Поэкспериментирую со всеми вариантами!